# How to fix 'cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file"

Tags: python-3.x, cx-oracle

I am trying to connect to Oracle through Raspberry Pi using cx_Oracle, getting below error while executing the python code.

> Error:"cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 32-bit Oracle Client library: "libclntsh.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". See https://oracle.github.io/odpi/doc/installation.html#linux for help"

```
import cx_Oracle
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import signal
import sys
#import cx_oracle


con = cx_Oracle.connect('dmin/ZtVAxM52OCWoWEdVe5cN@(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=swms.ctr1op5frvgj.ap-south-1.rds.amazonaws.com)(PORT=1521))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))')
#cursor = cx_Oracle.cursor()
#con = cx_Oracle.connect('test/test@orcl')
cursor = con.cursor()
cursor.execute("update BIN_DTL set B_STATUS='110' where B_ID='1001'")
con.commit()
print("DONE")
cursor.close()
con.close()
```

Comment: Check other related questions like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996329/how-can-i-insert-rows-into-oracle-sql-databse-from-a-raspberry-pi-using-python

Answer (score 0):

cx_Oracle requires the Oracle Client libraries to be installed and this error indicates they are either not installed for not configured properly. As far as I know, however, Raspberry Pi uses an ARM architecture which is not currently supported by the Oracle Client libraries. You'll have to use some other means of communicating with the Oracle database -- likely via another machine which is capable of using the Oracle Client libraries. I'm sorry to be the bearer of bad news!